# D3 Collapsible Tree how to make it vertically scrollable

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I have a D3 collapsible tree, the problem is that a single node can have upto 4000 leaves. I would like to make it scrollable or expandable, i.e. the height should work for both 10 leaf nodes or several 1000.

Currently my height parameter is static, can anyone tell me how I can make it dynamic?

The following is the code:

```
$(function(){
var m = [20, 120, 20, 120],
    w = 1280 - m[1] - m[3],
    h = 80000 - m[0] - m[2],
    i = 0,
    root;

var tree = d3.layout.tree()
    .size([h, w]);

var diagonal = d3.svg.diagonal()
    .projection(function(d) { return [d.y, d.x]; });

var vis = d3.select("#modelPatterns").append("svg:svg")
    .attr("width", w + m[1] + m[3])
    .attr("height", h + m[0] + m[2])
  .append("svg:g")
    .attr("transform", "translate(" + m[3] + "," + m[0] + ")");

d3.json("./static/data/type1Tree.json", function(json) {
  root = json;
  root.x0 = h / 2;
  root.y0 = 0;

  function toggleAll(d) {
    if (d.children) {
      d.children.forEach(toggleAll);
      toggle(d);
    }
  }

  // Initialize the display to show a few nodes.
  root.children.forEach(toggleAll);
  //toggle(root.children[1]);
  //toggle(root.children[1].children[2]);
  //toggle(root.children[9]);
  //toggle(root.children[9].children[0]);

  update(root);
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In case it helps someone, I used the zoom function which enabled panning and zooming. This may suffice for what you're looking for when trying to make the graph scrollable so to speak.

```
 D3.select('svg')
      .call(D3.zoom()
        .scaleExtent([-5, 8])
        .extent([[0, 0], [300, 300]])
        .on('zoom', () => {
          D3.selectAll('g')
            .attr('transform', D3.event.transform);


          if (has('root.children', this) && this.root.children.length > 50) {
            this.updateAfterInit(this.root);
          } else {
            this.update(this.root);
          }

          // this.centerNode(this.root);
        })
        .filter(() => {

          const foundNode = this.N.findNodeByID(D3.event.srcElement.id.split('_')[1])
          if ( !!foundNode && D3.event.type === 'dblclick' && foundNode.data.type === 'SearchRelationspec') {
            return false;
          } else {
            return !D3.event.target.classList.contains('drawarea') && D3.event.type === 'dblclick';
          }
        })
```

Answer (score 0):

You can modify your update function like below code as per your need...

```
 function update(source) {

 var duration = d3.event && d3.event.altKey ? 5000 : 500;    

 // compute the new height
 var levelWidth = [1];
 var childCount = function(level, n) {
 if(n.children && n.children.length > 0) {
   if(levelWidth.length <= level + 1) levelWidth.push(0);      
   levelWidth[level+1] += n.children.length;
   n.children.forEach(function(d) {`
     childCount(level + 1, d);
   });
 }
 };

 childCount(0, root);  

 newHeight = d3.max(levelWidth) * 60; // 20 pixels per line    

 tree = tree.size([newHeight, width]);

 d3.select("svg").remove();//TO REMOVE THE ALREADY SVG CONTENTS AND RELOAD ON EVERY UPDATE

 svg = d3.select("body").append("svg");

 svg.attr("width", width + margin.right + margin.left)
 .attr("height", newHeight + margin.top + margin.bottom)
 .append("g")
 .attr("transform", "translate(" + margin.left + "," + margin.top + ")");

 // Compute the new tree layout.
 var nodes = tree.nodes(root).reverse(),
 links = tree.links(nodes);

 // Normalize for fixed-depth.
 nodes.forEach(function(d) { d.y = d.depth * 180; });

 // Update the nodes…
 var node = svg.selectAll("g.node")
   .data(nodes, function(d) { return d.id || (d.id = ++i); });

 // Enter any new nodes at the parent's previous position.
 var nodeEnter = node.enter().append("g")
   .attr("class", "node")
   .attr("transform", function(d) { return "translate(" + source.y0 + "," +                     source.x0 + ")"; })
   .on("click", click);

 nodeEnter.append("circle")
   .style("fill", function(d) { return d._children ? "lightsteelblue" : "#fff"; });

 nodeEnter.append("text")
   .attr("x", function(d) { return d.children || d._children ? -10 : 10; })
   .attr("dy", "-.75em")
   .attr("text-anchor", function(d) { return d.children || d._children ? "end" : "start"; })
   .text(function(d) { return d.name; })
   .style("fill-opacity", 1e-2);

 nodeEnter.append("text")
   .attr("x", function(d) { return d.children || d._children ? -10 : 10; })
   .attr("dy", "1.00em")
   .attr("text-anchor", function(d) { return d.children || d._children ? "end" : "start"; })
   .text(function(d) { return d.info1; })
   .style("fill-opacity", 1e-2);

 // Transition nodes to their new position.
 var nodeUpdate = node.transition()
   .duration(duration)
   .attr("transform", function(d) { return "translate(" + d.y + "," + d.x + ")"; });

 nodeUpdate.select("circle")
   .attr("r", 6)
   .style("fill", function(d) { return d._children ? "lightsteelblue" : "#fff"; });

 nodeUpdate.selectAll("text")
   .style("fill-opacity", 4);

 // Transition exiting nodes to the parent's new position.
 var nodeExit = node.exit().transition()
   .duration(duration)
   .attr("transform", function(d) { return "translate(" + source.y + "," +     source.x + ")"; })
   .remove();

 nodeExit.selectAll("text")
   .style("fill-opacity", 1e-6);

 // Update the links…
 var link = svg.selectAll("path.link")
   .data(links, function(d) { return d.target.id; });

 // Enter any new links at the parent's previous position.
 link.enter().insert("path", "g")
   .attr("class", "link")
   .attr("d", function(d) {
     var o = {x: source.x0, y: source.y0};
     return diagonal({source: o, target: o});
   });

 // Transition links to their new position.
 link.transition()
   .duration(duration)
   .attr("d", diagonal);

 // Transition exiting nodes to the parent's new position.
 link.exit().transition()
   .duration(duration)
   .attr("d", function(d) {
     var o = {x: source.x, y: source.y};
     return diagonal({source: o, target: o});
   })
   .remove();

 // Stash the old positions for transition.
 nodes.forEach(function(d) {
 d.x0 = d.x;
 d.y0 = d.y;
 });
```

It will give you a dynamic size tree and serve for any number of nodes in the tree.
I hope this will solve your purpose.

Comment: In case someone stubbles across this like I did. the diagonal function can look like this 
// Creates a curved (diagonal) path from parent to the child nodes
  diagonal(s, d) {
    return `M ${s.y} ${s.x}
            C ${(s.y + d.y) / 2} ${s.x},
              ${(s.y + d.y) / 2} ${d.x},
              ${d.y} ${d.x}`;
  }


source comes from the root ndoe, and the duration is a number in milliseconds